# Can't cut certain faces with knife tool

Tags: modeling, vertices, faces, edges, knife-tool

I keep running into an issue where I try cutting on a face with a vertex and pressing the Z key or whatever corresponding key to cut with a straight line, but when I reach the bottom and click nothing happens... Sometimes it works fine but it depends on what face I am cutting... How can I fix this and make it where I can cut wherever?

Edit: I have added my .blend file and an image of where I want it cut:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Failures to K or Ctrl-R, cut, are often useful pointers to hidden errors in the mesh.. usually doubled faces or vertices. Try H hiding bits and pieces around the error.. jiggling vertices around in case they are hiding duplicates. (Also, assuming the target geometry _exists_, not generated by a modifier) Folks won't be able to help you specifically without a failing portion of the mesh in front of them.. if stuck, please share on https://blend-exchange.com/ .. until then, this post is likely to be voted 'unclear'.

Comment: @RobinBetts I am doing this for a business... It is a 3D model of a building and it has certain names, addresses, and sensitive information on it so will people be able to see the image textures on blend-exchange.com?

Comment: Hi,  @prestonferry.. for sure,  you would certainly want your sample to be anonymized .. if possible, make a copy of  a minimal representative portion of the mesh, all materials removed, as a new object,  and append that object to  a brand new empty .blend file.

Comment: @RobinBetts how can I remove all materials and just make it a wireframe, or whatever it needs to be?

Comment: Just delete all the materials from the duplicate object's material slots, before appending to the new file.

Comment: @RobinBetts I have posted an image and a .blend file

Comment: I've uploaded your file. All is fine with the knife. Nonetheless, if you hide the parts you don't want to cut, this is easier to manipulate.

Comment: Hi @lemon... The knife is not cutting through as when I click the vertices it doesn't cut... That's the issue I'm having... If you were able to fix it, please tell me how :)

Comment: just hide the other parts as they may conflict with the face you want to cut.

Comment: @prestonferry did you take care of the duplicate overlapping vertices? these prevent the knife from cutting properly as pointed out in the first comment. there are 200+ of them when i selected all vertices then pressed 'm' > *merge by distance*.

Comment: How do I go about removing them?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie it might also be useful for you to know that I created the bottom layer by extruding the bottom face of the building... How could I better to it so I don't have this issue again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in a situation like the first attempt illustrated below, trying to cut from a vertex on one face, across another which is not connected to it.

[image]

In your situation, If you <kbd>H</kbd> hide any foreground clutter, and switch on Automerge, with 'Split Edges and Faces' checked:

[image]

... with your Snap set to 'Vertex and 'Active' , you can kick Blender into joining the faces by snapping orthogonally to the separated edge, after which the cut will work, as shown in the second attempt, above.

**Edit** in response to comments

At the moment, you have a continuous edge along the bottom of your frontage:

[image]

With Automerge set as shown above, and Snapping set as described, you can <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> snap that edge to an existing vertex on that level, which will insert vertices at intersections along its length:

[image]

You can delete the face below the edge:

[image]

.. and, having <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - selected all the components of the now divided bottom edge, <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> extrude them downward, snapping to a vertex at the bottom level. This will create all the cuts you wanted to make, in one go.

[image]

Comment: What do I select when I press H?

Comment: @prestonferry .. only a suggestion to make your job easier.. I hid all the faces  of 
 protruding buttresses  to make the bits you wanted to cut more visible, that's all.

Comment: Please don't hesitate to tell me if this is too much to ask, but could you edit the answer and show me with my own Blender file? Maybe that would help... If not we'll probably need to find another way to go about conversing because I think I'm having trouble understanding...

Comment: @prestonferry see edit.. hope it helps.. quite difficult to illustrate on your model. You could have a shot at becoming more familiar with the behaviour of Automerge and snapping, on less fiddly geometry.

Comment: Took some time to figure out but it worked... Do I do this for the rest of the faces I can't cut on? Thanks :)

Comment: @prestonferry Glad it worked ! It depends on what you want, Sometimes it's better to model separate parts as separate parts, sometimes you want a continuous manifold surface. If the front of your building had been a single surface in the first place, with _extruded_ buttresses, then the cuts would have worked first time. I wouldn't know what the cuts are for..

Comment: What are extruded buttresses?

Comment: And how can I tell, for future reference?

Comment: 'Buttress' was the only name I could think of for the protrusions at the front of the building. At the moment the model is made of separated plane-faces, with vertices not aligned, so M > merge by distance doesn't have anything to weld together. If the building had been made, say, from a cube, with the panels Ctrl R cut into it and E extruded where wanted, then the whole thing could be a single surface, and more conventional modelling tools like K would work.